# Unit testing on Android NDK

Tags: unit-testing, android-ndk

How do you run unit tests on Android native code (native C/C++, *not* Java)? So far I've only found [one](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-ndk/Juvhzcoa38w) similar question, and the answer says use junit with JNI, which I don't want to do (adding JNI calls seems unnecessarily complicated for unit testing, and is not really a unit test of the native code anyway).

Does CppUnit (also suggested there) really work on Android? Note that I want the tests to run natively on the device, not on the host development environment. [This](http://sourceforge.net/p/cppunit/patches/68/) looks like an Android port, is it worth looking at?

An official Google test framework like [googletest](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/) would be ideal, but that doesn't seem to work with the NDK.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I use googletest through NDK I use a $(call import-module to bring in the main .so and then have a single file in the executable that looks like

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
#if RUN_GTEST
    INIT_GTESTS(&argc,(char**)argv);
    RUN_ALL_GTESTS();
#endif
}
```

And then I build that with BUILD_EXECUTABLE, deploy it like:

```
find libs/ -type f -print -exec adb push {} /data/local/tmp \;
```

and run it like

```
adb shell LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/local/tmp:/vendor/lib:/system/lib /data/local/tmp/gtest
```

So it doesn't test the application life cycle but it tests all the unit tests.

If I needed to test something with a UI I could do something similar but make what's now 'main' a native function and invoke it when the activity is loaded.

Comment: Thanks! We'll check this out. I didn't realize that you could build executables too.

Comment: Also you can build and link gtest_main.cc.

Comment: Suppose that I want to actually use JNI calls, how can I get or create JavaVM*?

Comment: @syvex, just implement `jint JNI_OnLoad(JavaVM* vm, void* reserved);` and store the `JavaVM *`

Comment: How should JNI_OnLoad work? This is a pure C++ executable.

Comment: Is this still possible ten years later? Shell prints "Segmentation fault" to me, with no other info and nothing in logcat.