# Googletest for Android NDK

Tags: android, c++, unit-testing, android-ndk, tdd

I checked a previous answer about unit test for Android, where it is suggested Googletest as a [good option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126967/unit-testing-on-android-ndk). However, I got a look into the Google C++ Testing Framework - [Googletest](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/). About platforms, I don't see anything mentioning support to Android. Could someone tell anything, if there is some way of using it with Android devices - e.g. steps to build a toolchain, etc?

Comment: In new NDK you can use cmake so its now much more simple:
`TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(${PROJECT_NAME} gtest)`

Comment: @DawidDrozd you can use `target_link_libraries`, but there is no script that builds **gtest**. You need [few more lines in CMakeLists.txt](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46448545/192373), don't you?

Comment: Yes there is. I mean gtest has already CMakeLists you need only add subdirectory

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to built Googletest for Android to be able to run it with your toolchain, as you working with cross-compilation.

Download source code of googletest

```
$ mkdir googletest
$ cd googletest
$ svn checkout http://googletest.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ .
```

Copy jni directory to googletest directory

```
$ cd /path/to/this/git
$ cp -r jni googletest/
```

run ndk-build script

```
$ cd googletest/ $ ndk-build
```

You can find libgtest.a in googletest/obj/local/armeabi/libgtest.a

Source:  [sfuku7 / googletest_android_ndk-build - github](https://github.com/sfuku7/googletest_android_ndk-build)

Answer (score 32):

GoogleTest is now distributed with the NDK (mainly because it's used by the NDK test suite itself).

It's very easy to use in your own projects, see $NDK/sources/third_party/googletest/README.NDK for usage examples.

Comment: But seem like it is rather a old one (older than 1.6.0). Probably now, fetching the sources and building is the right way as in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 2):

**jni/Android.mk:**

```
  LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

  include $(CLEAR_VARS)
  LOCAL_MODULE := foo
  LOCAL_SRC_FILES := foo.cpp
  include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

  include $(CLEAR_VARS)
  LOCAL_MODULE := foo_unittest
  LOCAL_SRC_FILES := foo_unittest.cpp
  LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := foo
  LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := googletest_main
  include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)

  $(call import-module,third_party/googletest)
```

Answer (score -1):

This gradle plugin https://github.com/fsbarata/ndktest-plugin will help you get the Googletest working. Still worth to look at the Googletest framework though.