# android c++ unit testing in visual studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, visual-c++, android-ndk, visual-studio-2015

I've been creating a native android c++ library for audio processing using Visual Studio 2015 and the Android NDK. It works well but what I would really love to be able to do is to write unit tests as well; and as far as I can work out there is no support for unit testing in this case. Does anyone know a way of doing this? (preferably with some reasonably detailed instructions, given my relative lack of experience with C++ and VS). I'd rather do this in Visual Studio rather than using the approach that I've seen mentioned of using JUnit and JNI from another IDE.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt you'll find anything with fancy IDE integration, but for the NDK in general you can use [gtest](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/) for unit testing.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22075341/632035) shows how to do this from within the NDK, but I don't know what extra steps you'll need to make this work within VS.