# Using google Test with Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, googletest

[gradle-ndk-gtest-sample](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/docs/src/samples/native-binaries/google-test/build.gradle)

[Android NDK with](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46429958/android-ndk-with-google-test)

[README.NDK](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:sSSdx6HDdr8J:https://chromium.googlesource.com/android_tools/%2B/7fc902d157a9aed7a2b68adc9c69181b3a43cd58/ndk/sources/third_party/googletest/README.NDK%20&cd=4&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=ca&client=firefox-b-ab)

I have been trying to configure my Android NDK project for use with Google Test. I started with [native-activity sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk/tree/master/native-activity) as the base project and began following the guides above. I inserted the code from the first link into my root build.gradle. I am really not having any success. It looks like i was able to generate the test library:

```
./libs/googleTest/1.7.0/lib/osx/libgtest.a
./libs/googleTest/1.7.0/lib/linux/libgtest.a
./app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/x86_64/libnative_app_glue.a
./app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/x86_64/libFOO.a
./app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/x86_64/libgtest.a
./app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/arm64-v8a/libnative_app_glue.a
./app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/arm64-v8a/libFOO.a
./app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/arm64-v8a/libgtest.a
```

But I don't know where to go from here. How do I actually run the tests and see if they passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like https://github.com/DanAlbert/GTestJNI. It's an alternative test runner for JUnit and GTest that exposes GTests as if they were JUnit, so you can just run your normal androidTests and they'll run your GTests for you.

Some day I want to get this either added to the NDK or at least made trivial to add to a project as a git submodule or something, but for now you can merge the pieces of that into your project.

Comment: It is added now - https://github.com/android/ndk-samples/tree/main/unit-test