# Is there a way to test JNI method without writing Java wrapper?

Tags: java, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I know we can write some Java native method to test JNI's C/C++ code, but it takes too much time and most of the C/C++ code doesn't need to be accessed from Java, is there a way to test them programmatically?

Comment: If you want to test C/C++ code that is not accessed from Java, you can use a C/C++ unit test framework.

Comment: Well, the JVM itself is written in C, isn't it?  But it's a lot easier to just test JNI code like you would test Java code.  Why do you want to test your JNI code like this?

Comment: @AndrewHenle Some of the C code doesn't have to be accessed from Java. e.g. codec tools.

Comment: @AndyThomas Thanks, I am not familiar with C/C++ test framework at all, is there any way to do it in Android Studio?

Comment: @MrROY - Here's an existing question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18126967/unit-testing-on-android-ndk.

Comment: JNI C++ code needs to be tested from Java. Otherwise you aren't testing it all.

Answer (score 0):

There are two sides for your question.

If you want to unit test the underlying C/C++ code that is normally used in the context of a Java Android application, you can use [googletest](https://code.google.com/p/googletest/). **googletest** is shipped with Android NDK (`third_party/googletest`), it is used to test NDK itself. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18137842/192373) you can find step-by-step instructions for running such unit tests.

This C code is often cross-platform, and it makes a lot of sense to also  compile it for the build machine, and test *natively* - without Android device or emulator.

But this approach cannot test the C code that actually uses JNI functions (e.g. those that are responsible for conversion from Java objects or data types to C/C++ and back). While the best practice is to keep such *wrapper* thin and simple, the reality often forces us to put some non-trivial logic into these functions. And even if it is simple, it should be testable.

To *unittest* a native method, you must **a)** mock the underlying C++ layers, **b)** mock the Java class that calls this native method, and **c)** mock any Java methods that are called from the native code. Then, you can use **JUnit** to run the tests on a device or emulator. Your code should be designed in a way that allows such deconstruction. Particularly, you need discipline that the JNI callbacks are only located in the wrapper classes, and Java-dependent code is not used in core.

Actually, if the design is clean enough and separation of roles is rigorous enough, you can run these Java tests on the host machine, not using Android device or emulator. Your C++ code should be able to build with host toolchain without the NDK extensions (e.g. `__android_log_print()`), and also run without Android environment (e.g. you can `FindClass("java/util/ArrayList")`, but not `FindClass("android/util/SparseArray")`).

Unfortunately, there seems to be no way Android Studio can help with this, but we use separate native **cmake** to build unit tests with host C compiler. Such tests cannot replace device-side testing, of course, but they are invaluable in CI environment.

**UPDATE**

If you are interested in this topic, you must read [Android JUnit Testing for Native Libraries](http://www.sureshjoshi.com/mobile/android-junit-native-libraries/) by [Suresh Joshi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/992509/sjoshi).

Comment: "Actually, if the design is clean enough and separation of roles is rigorous enough, you can run these Java tests on the host machine, not using Android device or emulator." - What do you mean by this? What does the separation of roles have to do with where you can test the code? It's a huge pain, but you can run JUnit tests on the host machine, but targeting host-compatible binaries (so - not exactly the same as testing the NDK compiled libs, but close). This lets you test whatever is accessible from Java.

Comment: @SJoshi you need clean design to handle this, because your C++ code should be able to build with host toolchain without the NDK extensions (e.g. `__android_log_print`), and also run without Android environment (e.g. you can `FindClass("java/util/ArrayList")`, but not `FindClass("android/util/SparseArray")`).

Comment: Ahh, okay, I see - I would have assumed that if there are native (non Android) unit tests, that not having NDK extensions baked in was a given as they wouldn't compile without the NDK. But, then again - it's better to never assume  :)

Comment: @SJoshi chapeau for https://stackoverflow.com/a/47325408/192373! I hope Google will pick up the glove and provide a framework for the Android-specific symbols and classes.